# Get First Input in first ul and its first li

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

Here's the markup:

```
<h3>Customers</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>
          <label for="customer115">Some Customer Name</label>
          <input id="customer115"  type="checkbox" value="115" name="customer115">
      </li>
      .. there are more <li> here...and so on
   </ul>
<h3>Dealers</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>
          <label for="dealer100">Some DealerName</label>
          <input id="dealer100"  type="checkbox" value="115" name="dealer115">
      </li>
      .. there are more <li> here...and so on
   </ul>
```

I'm trying to get reference to the customer checkbox for example so I can do a click() on it via XPath.  I'm doing this in Selenium so something like:

```
 string sXPath = string.Format(string.Format("//h3[text()='{0}']/ul/li/input[1]", "Customers"));

IWebElement firstCompanyCheckbox = GetElementByXPath(sXPath);
firstCompanyCheckbox.Click();
```

So far I can't figure out how to get to this reference, the above xPath does not find it.  I want to click that checkbox.

Comment: Isn't that XPath looking for a ul INSIDE an h3?

Comment: yes I caught that after posting this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ul` is not a child of `h3`. It is a sibling.  Adjust your XPath to use the [`following-sibling::` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)

```
//h3[text()='{0}']/following-sibling::ul/li/input[1]
```

If you want to ensure that you select the first `ul` and the first `li`, then add additional predicate filters:

```
//h3[text()='{0}']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li[1]/input[1]
```

Comment: I don't want to select the first ul, only the first li in the ul... but one question I do have is what if you have a series of <ul> and you want to iterate each one and check the first checkbox in each ul?

Comment: can you explain the :: and following-sibling in this case?  I'm new to XPath.

Comment: found it, should be {} so text()='{0}', I had []

Comment: `following-sibling` is an axis and `::` is the axis separator. If you don't specify an axis at a location step, the default is `child`. So, `/ul/li` is equivalent to `/child::ul/child::li`.  http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes

Answer (score 0):

You could also also simplify, in my opinion, that XPath by using an easier to read [CSS Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) as well:

```
ul:first li:first input[type='checkbox']
```

I'm sure there will be a lot of debate as to which is preferable: CSS vs XPath. But typically when I see my QA going the route of a complex XPath query. I try to find ways to implement "id" attributes on the elements or simplify the DOM elements for selecting.